# A question about the official Chinese translation of two passages from Nietzsche's books

Tags: translation, books, literature, modern

It can be inferred form Wikipedia that the tilte of Nietzsche's book "Menschliches, Allzumenschliches" is officially translated as 人性的，太人性的 to Chinese (cf. [Chinese Wikipedia](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-hans/%E4%BA%BA%E6%80%A7%E7%9A%84%EF%BC%8C%E5%A4%AA%E4%BA%BA%E6%80%A7%E7%9A%84?wprov=sfla1)).

My question concerns the official translation of two other passages from Nietzsches œuvre, namely the title of the first part of 人性的，太人性的, which is in German "Von den ersten und letzten Dingen", and the explanation of the title of the whole book in Nietzsches self-characterization/autobiography "Ecce homo": There it is written in German "wo ihr ideale Dinge seht, sehe ich - Menschliches, ach nur Allzumenschliches!".

I want to remark: I am not looking for your own translation of these sentences in case you speak both German and Chinese; I am looking for the official translation in a Chinese version of Nietzsche's books. This is a question for someone who has them available in Chinese, either at home or online.

[image: Menschliches, Allzumenschliches, Nietzsche]
[image: Ecce homo, Nietzsche]

Comment: most books translated into chinese language are not approved by the government. so, what is your definition of “**official** translation”?

Comment: @水巷孑蠻 With official I just meant a standard translation, like one Chinese scholar translating the whole work of Nietzsche in a uniform and consistent way. I didn't thought of government approval, but I know that Nietzsche is revered as a philosopher in China, and hence was translated and is available. Often one translation is considered as particularly "good" and outstanding by the public. That one could be called official. But any written and published translation counts as an answer. Thank you for your interest in the question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there’re pdf, or epub file of nietzsche’s books in simplified chinese

[人性的，太人性的](https://static2.file123.info/download/7e7ee3a2f2401a4c144f87ddb404547e533495bf)

on page 21 of the linked pdf

> Von den ersten und letzten Dingen

is translated as “關於最初的事物與最後的事物”

[瞧，這箇人](https://static2.file123.info/download/7e7ee3a2f940184d164b86d6bc04547c57379fb1)

on page 29(?) of the epub file

> wo ihr ideale Dinge seht, sehe ich - Menschliches, ach nur Allzumenschliches!

is translated as “你們看到的理想事物，在我看來卻是 - 人性的，啊，太人性的！”

have fun :)

Comment: 你引用的短语是官方翻译的吗？:)

Comment: @Pedroski, these’re quoted from the linked files 

Answer (score 1):

> Herbert Grönemeyer
>
> Und der Mensch heißt Mensch
> Weil er irrt und weil er kämpft
> Und weil er hofft und liebt
> Weil er mitfühlt und vergibt

The translation of "menschlich" depends on what you think "menschlich" means, which may be a long discussion. Self-destructive and absurd? Rubbish-loving?

Mensch: 人
menschlich: Mensch: human being, -lich: appearance, form, body, manner: 人性的 （意思很含糊。)

Wo ihr ideale Dinge seht, sehe ich - Menschliches, ach nur allzu menschliches.
Where you see ideals, I only see human, all too human things.
在你看到理想的地方，我只看到太人性化的东西。

Ecce homo: 看这个人

Pontius Pilate probably wanted to emphasise that this person, Jesus, is just an ordinary man, not a God.

Von den ersten und letzten Dingen
about the first and last things (Whatever they might be!)
谈论第一件事和最后一件事。

Alle Übersetzungen sind vom Übersetzungsministerium zugelassen.
All translations have been approved by the Ministry of Official Translations.
所有翻译都已获得官方翻译部的批准。