# Translation: Soft abstraction is not an ideal, it's a reconciliation!

Tags: translation, word-requests, culture, history

I'm looking for a Chinese translation of this 格言:

> English: Soft abstraction is not an ideal, it's a reconciliation!

> German: Weiche Abstraktion ist kein Ideal, sondern eine Versöhnung!

**What is meant with this to give context for a possible Chinese translation:**

Soft abstraction, a certain art style, not quite in opposition to hard abstraction, but rather in addition to it, is not meant to be an ideal way of painting which excludes and dominates other ways. It also does not claim a moral superiority or to educate the viewer.

Rather, it's a reconciliation or synthesis, in order to bridge a gap or dissolve artificial boundaries between the seemingly contradictory different art styles which were at times in opposition.

It's a new way of thinking by painting which emphasizes the manifold of possible matters, but not their ambiguity, regardless of the quality of their execution.

On a personal and emotional level of the artist, it's a reconciliation with a past of naivety and ascetics which takes place  in the aftermath, in the creative incarnation of the third reality.

**Preliminary thoughts on a possible translation:**

Soft abstraction is a fixed term which is usually translated into Chinese by 软抽象绘画. Ideal, I would translate by 理想事物 - in regards of the word choice I've learned and figured out in my previous [question](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/55336/21646) on Nietzsche, to generate a resemblance for the Chinese audience with known texts, and because it's exactly what is philosophically meant.

For "reconciliation", I've no idea. The Pleco dictionary pretends the Chinese language doesn't have an equivalent word.

The German "sondern" in the German version of the 格言 could be translated as 而.

Comment: I think “轻抽象” might be the right translation for soft abstraction. See: https://ucca.org.cn/lab/soft-abstraction-as-constellation/

Comment: Thanks, you are probably right. Feel free to use 轻. All that I can say is that Weibo has a hashtag with 软抽象. Therefore, I concluded this term is commonplace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, an art question! Absolutely unqualified in this respect. I can't really understand this waste of words:

> It's a new way of thinking by painting which emphasizes the manifold
> of possible matters, but not their ambiguity, regardless of the
> quality of their execution.

but I would tentatively put forward:

Weiche Abstraktion ist kein Ideal, sondern eine Versöhnung!
Lax abstraction is not ideal, but it is an appeasement.
松散的抽象并不理想，但它是一种安抚。

Assuming 'weich' to mean here 'not stringent, not strict'

Comment: Thank you for always answering my questions! Even without understanding my a little bit confuse writing and flow of thoughts, I like your translation.  The translation of appeasement instead of reconciliation is a good solution and leads to the intended meaning.

Comment: Are you sure we can say 理想 like this? Can we also say 一个理想事物 instead?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I am busy being a carpenter and a plumber these last few days. Yes, I find "并不理想，" fine. The meaning of "Weiche Abstraktion" is a harder nut to crack, so I just left that as 松散的抽象. "Abstaktion" seems to refer to the process of discovering underlying patterns in things. Exactly what is meant by '"Weiche Abstraktion" is somewhat abstract, for me!!

Comment: Okay , thanks again!